# When to use Location http header versus Link http header in API responses?

Tags: api, rest, http-headers

I am used to sending http(s) link value in Location http response header. However there appears to be a new standard that improves on this Location header with a new Link http response header, as described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5988#section-5.

Do both of them address the same problem? If so, when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

The Location header has a a specific meaning: it should point to the destination of a redirect, or it should point to a newly created resource in conjunction with a `201 Created` response.

The `Link` header should be used for *other* kinds of relationships. The Link header supports many types of relationship, for example:

- Pointing to the `author` of a resource
- Pointing to a `stylesheet` that may be used with a resource.
- Pointing to a `collection` that a resource belongs in
- Pointing to the `predecessor-version` of a resource
- Pointing to the `next` page.

The full list of these relationship types can be found on the [IANA Link Relations page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml)